# Can chrome extensions read data from internal chrome*:// pages?

Tags: google-chrome, security, google-chrome-extensions

Most Chrome extensions ask to `"read/modify data on all websites"`. But can they read, for instance, data from `chrome-extensions://`?

From experience, I know that most web clippers simply don't work on internal `chrome://` pages. But could they? Could they read say any data I enter into or view in a password manager extension like LastPass etc.? Another way of putting it is: can chrome extension read data from other extensions? Can it log keystrokes as I am typing stuff into other extensions and internal chrome pages?

Answer (score 0):

I'm struggling to make extensions work on internal pages like these.
I believe in default configuration it is impossible.
There seems to be flag allowing it, but from what I understand even if enabled the extensions have to explicitly ask for permission to work on these pages.

EDIT: After researching a bit more I found out that you can allow extensions to work on `chrome://` pages this way, but it is impossible to make them work on `chrome-extension://` pages without editing the code